# Store txt file values into 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, 2d

Firstly, here is my code http://pastebin.com/BxpE7aFA.

Now. I want to read a text file which looks like this http://pastebin.com/d3PWqSTV
and put all those integers into an array, called level. level has a size of 100x25, which is declared at the top.

My only problem now is where you see the ???. How do I get the char from the file, and put that into level[i][j]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the code of initialization of a matrix, it should be `int level[HEIGHT][WIDTH];` not  `int level[WIDTH][HEIGHT];` also, your data rows are shorter than `WIDTH`. The code works the next way: we loop through all lines of a level matrix, read a row from a file by `(file >> row)` instruction, if read was successfull, then we populate row in a level matrix, otherwise we read EOF so break from loop.

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<fstream>
    #include<string>
    #include <limits>

    static const int WIDTH = 100;
    static const int HEIGHT = 25;

    int main()
    {
        int level[HEIGHT][WIDTH];

        for(int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++)
            {
                level[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }

        std::ifstream file("Load/Level.txt");
        for(int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++)
        {
            std::string row;
            if (file >> row) {
                for (int j = 0; j != std::min<int>(WIDTH, row.length()) ; ++j)
                {
                    level[i][j] = row[j]-0x30;
                }
                std::cout << row << std::endl;
            } else break;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Oh really.. Didn't notice that! Thanks

Comment: By the way, where should I check if level[i][j] is == 1 or 0?
Within the for loop, or outside?

Comment: It depends on what you want to accomplish, I'd separated input of data and application ligic. So if you want to build a structure of your level from level matrix, just write another loops to do it.

Comment: I want to draw textures based on what number row is

Answer (score 1):

You can use `file >> level[i][j];` to populate your 2D char array `level[ ][ ]` with the contents of `level.txt`.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

static const int WIDTH = 100;
static const int HEIGHT = 25;
char level[HEIGHT][WIDTH]={0};


int main()
{

    std::ifstream file;
    file.open("level.txt");

    if(file.is_open())
    {
            std::cout << "File Opened successfully!!!. Reading data from file into array" << std::endl;
            while(!file.eof())
            {
                    for(int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++)
                    {
                            for(int j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++)
                            {
                                    //level[i][j] = ???
                                    file >> level[i][j];
                                    std::cout << level[i][j];
                            }
                            std::cout << std::endl;
                    }
            }

    }
    file.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This will not work because file with data does not contain spaces.

Comment: @nikitoz ooh, that's why!